# Run a given command on every subpath of a long path

Tags: shell-script, zsh, chmod

Say I have a long path such as:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

I would like to run a command **only** on each of the subpaths of the path:

e.g. If my command is `cmd`, I am looking for a one-liner that can do (perhaps using a one-line loop)

```
cmd /a
cmd /a/b
cmd /a/b/c
cmd /a/b/c/d
cmd /a/b/c/d/e
cmd /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

**One** of the reasons why I need this (I need it for other things as well), is because I would like to give somebody from my unix group the ability to `cd` incrementally her way to `/a/b/c/d/e/f`. To do this, I think I need to run `chmod g+x` on each of these subpaths (not sure if there is an alternative). Note that I want to avoid `chmod -R g+x /a`.

I work primarily on zsh so I wonder if there is anything that takes advantage of specific zsh features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `zsh` config file:

```
function pathargs {
  local P=$1; local L=${#P}; shift
  local N=1; while [[ $N -le $L ]]; do
    [[ ($N == 1 && ${P[1]} = '/') || \
       ${P[$N]} != '/' && ($N == $L || ${P[$N+1]} == '/') ]] \
    && $@ ${P:0:$N}
    N=$(($N+1))
  done
}
```

Example:

```
% pathargs /abc/def/ghi/jkl echo
/
/abc
/abc/def
/abc/def/ghi
/abc/def/ghi/jkl
```

You can use it with `chmod -R g+x` instead of `echo`. The command will be called on the top-most directories first.

Comment: This looks great Stéphane. I'm not sure I understand the difference between using `-n 1` and not using it. How are they exactly different?

Comment: I removed the feature, it was the same difference as `xargs` and `xargs -n 1`. The new (and cleaner) function will always do to the latter: Call one instance of the command on every argument.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
path=/a/b/c/d/e/f
while test "$path" != "/"; do
    chmod g+x "$path"
    path=$(dirname "$path")
done
```

Comment: Would by nice if `dirname` could be used recursively from the commandline, but I don't see that happen. +1 for cleanest script.

Comment: You could incorporate this idea into a function like Stéphane's if you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

Quick to type and works in all shells:

```
(while [ "$PWD" != / ]; do cmd .; cd ..; done)
```

The parentheses keep the directory change local. Like your example, the root directory is omitted. If you want to stop if running `cmd` fails, add `set -e;` after the opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

How about `find start_directory -type d -exec my_cmd {} \;`

- start_directory is `/a` in your example
- `type d` indicates only directories. `type f` for files. Leave this argument for both files and directories.
- my_cmd is `cmd` in your example
- `{}` is replaced with the directory name found
- `\;` don't forget it, the command won't work without it.

**Example1**: 
This will print out all full path directory names under /home:

```
find /home -type d -exec echo {} \;
```

**Example2**: This is your use case:

```
find /a -type d -exec echo chmod g+x {} \;
```

It prints the commands, doesn't execute them. You can check if it is really what you want and if so, you can pipe it to bash (or zsh if you wish):

```
find /a -type d -exec echo chmod g+x {} \; | bash
```

Comment: Thanks @jippie, but each of my subpaths contain many, many other folders on which I don't want to run my command. I would also like to avoid typing the name of the subpaths one by one (i.e. I am looking for something that can take `/a/b/c/d/e/f/` directly)

Comment: So use the variation with bash, but instead of piping it to bash redirect it to a file. Remove the unwanted lines, then execute the file. `find /a -type d -exec echo chmod g+x {} \; > /tmp/my_commands.sh` followed by `vi /tmp/my_commands` or a smart grep ... . then `. /tmp/my_commands` to execute the lines. *Just don't forget the `echo`* or all commands will be executed right away.

Comment: This is exactly what roseck said he didn't want.