# Change file name in different path

Tags: bash, command-line

I would like to know how to rename the same log file which is in different path.
I mean, the log file is in `/main/rel/1.2`, `/main/rel/1.3`, `/main/rel/1.4`, `/main/rel/1.5` etc. I want just do it from `/main/rel` to all the path.

Could this be possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand your question. What do you mean by "change the same log file" . Would you like to rename it? Modify the contents?

Comment: You are right, i mean just rename.

Comment: would you please elaborate ? If you could provide some examples in detail, it would be very helpful and much faster to figure out.

Comment: Is [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132237/26909) what you're looking for?

Comment: I have the same log file (e.g. file.log) saved in different path like /main/rel/1.2 /main/rel/1.3 /main/rel/1.4 /main/rel/1.5. 
I'd like rename this file in file.log.OLD in each path but just with one command run from /main/rel/ without having to go into each path. Clearer now?

Comment: Then perhaps [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36974/2690) will help.

Answer (score 1):

using `find` to find all files you want to rename and running an `exec` script:
`

```
 find /main/rel -name file.log -exec mv '{}' '{}.OLD' \;
```

this will run the `mv` cmd on all found files, the `{}` (escaped so the shell doesn't do weird things) will be replaced by the filename.
this allows you to easily add extra characters to the original filename (e.g. append `.OLD`).

anyhow, checkout `logrotate`, which is a tool that was created for the job you want to do.
it not only rotates logfiles for you (e.g. rename `logfile` to `logfile.0`; but before it moves `logfiles.0` to `logfile.1`; compress older logfiles so they don't take up much space; delete very old logfiles) but also notifies the daemon that writes the logfile that it probably needs to reopen the new one (else you might rename your `logfile` to `foobar.bak`, only to discover that the server keeps appending to `foobar.bak`...)

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think there's a single command to do so.
you can do renaming these files one-by-one.

```
/main/rel$mv 1.2/somelog 1.2/some_newlog; mv 1.3/somelog 1.3/some_newlog; mv 1.4/somelog 1.4/some_newlog
```

and etc...
However, you can write a script to do such job:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in 1.{2..4}
do
    `mv $dir/some.txt $dir/somenew.txt`
done
```

NOTE: Above Script Should be saved in "/main/rel" and you have to run this Bash script from there only.

Comment: For the script I would recommend something more like:

for file in \`ls $1\` ; do mv $1/$file $1/\`echo $file | sed "s/some/somenew/g"\`; done

That way you can pass in a directory as an argument

Comment: In your script we have to give the Directory/subDirectories as argument.
Also If I run this script as: `./rename.sh 1.{2..6}` then its only working for /main/rel/1.2 not for all i.e. 1.2,1.3,1.4, etc.